# Array of dataframes, get max of each and sum in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have an array of dataframes similar to this:

```
index   date    profit  required    symbol  category
0   2008-04-01  5.0 3   AA  cat1
1   2008-04-02  4.0 6   AA  cat1
2   2008-04-03  1.0 2   AA  cat1
3   2008-04-04  2.0 3   AA  cat1
4   2008-04-05  3.0 4   AA  cat1
5   2008-04-06  0.0 7   AA  cat1

index   date    profit  required    symbol  category
0   2008-04-01  1.0 3   AA  cat1
1   2008-04-02  1.0 2   AA  cat1
2   2008-04-03  1.0 2   AA  cat1
3   2008-04-04  2.0 3   AA  cat1
4   2008-04-05  3.0 2   AA  cat1
5   2008-04-06  3.0 1   AA  cat1

index   date    profit  required    symbol  category
0   2008-04-01  3.0 1   AB  cat1
1   2008-04-02  5.0 1   AB  cat1
2   2008-04-03  1.0 1   AB  cat1
3   2008-04-04  3.0 3   AB  cat1
4   2008-04-05  3.0 2   AB  cat1
5   2008-04-06  4.0 1   AB  cat1

index   date    profit  required    symbol  category
0   2008-04-01  5.0 1   AC  cat2
1   2008-04-02  4.0 1   AC  cat2
2   2008-04-03  3.0 12  AC  cat2
3   2008-04-04  2.0 1   AC  cat2
4   2008-04-05  3.0 1   AC  cat2
5   2008-04-06  4.0 1   AC  cat2
```

Symbol and category are unique for each dataframe: I've made them into columns but they're single values and could also be used as such.

What I'm trying to do is, for each symbol and each category:

- simple sum of all profits
- sum of the max required of each dataframe

I could easily do this in pure Python (pseudo-code: some things made easier):

```
result = {}
for df in dfs:
    result[df.symbol]["profits_generated"] += df["profit"].sum()
    result[df.symbol]["sum_of_max_required"] += df["required"].max()
    # same for category...
```

My questions are: can this be translated into pandas and would it be more efficient or just better to read?

I can do the profits sum part, something like:

```
pd.concat(dfs).groupby("symbol").sum()["profit"]
```

But not the sum of max for each single dataframe.

Comment: What do you mean "max margin" of each dataframe? Just the max of the "required" series?  Can you post your desired output as a frame?

Comment: I'm stupid, sorry... I meant "max required". The column name.

Comment: Do you want the sum of all the maxes? Or just the max of each frame?

Comment: The max of each frame, but grouped by symbol. So for example AA would be 7+3, AB=3, AC=12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adding `keys` when you do `concat`

```
pd.concat(dfs,keys=range(len(dfs))).groupby([df.index.get_level_values(0),df.symbol])["profit"].max().sum()
```